# AST conversion in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've an AST whose root node is of type `E.Root`. I need to convert it into an AST with root node whose type is `I.Root`.

I can now define a function `eToI` with type signature :

```
eToI :: E.Root -> AdditionalInfo -> I.Root
```

However, both the ASTs share a lot of nodes. So, the function `eToF` has a lot of boilerplate code building `I's` nodes from `E's` nodes which are essentially the same.

I would like to solve these 2 problems :

1. At the type level, avoid defining the nodes of `I`. I have all the nodes
   of `E` defined. I define what nodes change in `I`. Can I have the
   compiler generate all the types in `I`, by somehow mapping what
   needs to change?
2. At the value level, I'd only want to define transformations for the
       nodes that change like (assuming E's A is mapped to I's Z ..) :

   ```
       aToZ :: E.A -> AdditionalInfo -> I.Z
       bToY :: E.B -> AdditionalInfo -> I.Y
   ```

   Now, can the compiler generate a function like eToI?

   ```
       eToI :: E.Root -> AdditionalInfo -> I.Root
   ```

What's Haskell's idiomatic approach to do this?

Comment: What is different between the two AST types?

Comment: Scrap Your Boilerplate, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can factor out the common aspects of `E.Root` and `I.Root` into one ore more reusable datatypes. It usually also helps to hide the `AdditionalInfo -> ...` in a monad or an applicative functor. For example, here's some pseudocode:

```
module Common where
  {-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
  data Reusable root = ... root ...
    deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

module E where
  import Common
  data Root = Leaf (Reusable Root) | Node Root

module I where
  {-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
  import Common

  import Data.Monoid

  data Root = Root [Reusable Root]
    deriving Monoid

module Transform where
  import Common
  import qualified E
  import qualified I

  import Control.Applicative
  import Control.Monad.Reader
  import Data.Monoid

  type AdditionalInput = ...
  type F = Reader AdditionalInput

  convertRoot :: E.Root -> F I.Root
  convertRoot (Leaf reusable) =
    traverse convertRoot reusable
  convertRoot (Node left right) =
    liftA2 mappend (convertRoot left) (convertRoot right)
```

Now I can use `traverse` to convert between `Reusable E.Root` and `Reusable I.Root`.

Comment: I think the OP's intent is to 1) reduce the boilerplate by not writing *type declarations* for I (since most of I's AST is similar to E), and then 2) only write *functions explicitly converting I values to E values* (for those few types that are different), and not write the rest. Your code is probably what he already has. This problem could be solved with Template Haskell, but could be ugly.

Comment: @tanmaig: If the approach from my answer is applicable at all, it achieves both these goals. In particular: (1) The type declaration for Reusable is written only once, not twice in E and I. (2) There is an explicit convertRoot, because E.Root and I.Root differ, but there is no explicit convertReusable, because the automatically generated traverse does the job just fine.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know how traverse will work on a 'Reusable' traversable type with multiple type params instead of just one. Say, the AST is: ```data Reusable aRoot bRoot cRoot``` How will the traversable typeclass be derived in that case?

Comment: @tanmaig: Ah, that's a good question. I agree that in this case, plain `traverse` is not good enough.